# Die Bedeutung von »Sauerei« und »Schweinerei«

Tags: difference, single-word-request

Als für Menschen angewandtes Adjektiv nutzen wir im Spanischen *perro* (wörtlich *Rüde*; Bedeutung: sehr schlecht) schon als  gewissermaßen beleidigend, aber dessen Femininum, *perra* (wörtlich *Hündin*), wäre um ein Vielfaches beleidigender (nämlich äußerst beleidigend!). Ich glaube, das ist der Ursprung folgender Frage.

Ich vermute, die Bedeutung von *Sauerei* und *Schweinerei* ist beinahe die gleiche. Im Chat wurden mir aber ein paar Gegenbeispiele angeboten, und es wurde darauf hingewiesen, sie seien nicht exakte Synonyme (ob zwei Wörter exakte Synonyme sind und was exakte Synonyme sind, ist eine schwierige Frage: lassen wir uns hier einfach *exakte Synonyme* als völlig austauschbar oberflächlich definieren).

> *Schweinerei* wird für Dinge genutzt, die man für moralisch verwerflich hält (insbesondere bzgl. Sexualität), *Sauerei* nicht.

Wie lässt sich dieser Unterschied erklären?

Comment: Ich habe die Tags bearbeitet. Bei diesen Wörtern spielt weder das biologische Geschlecht noch das grammatikalische Geschlecht irgendeine Rolle. Grund: Wer an das männliche Schwein denkt, sagt *Eber*, aber die *Eberei* ist nicht verbreitet.

Comment: Ich würde mich nicht sehr auf den  von dir  angegebenen unterschiedlichen Gebrauch festlegen. Beide Wörter können in jeder Situation verwendet werden, für einen umgestoßenen Eimer mit Schmutzwasser, im moralischen und auch pornographischem Sinn. Manche Leute interpretieren gerne Unterschiede in Wörter, obwohl sie in sprachlichen Dingen gar nicht die nötige Erfahrung haben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sauerei* enthält *die Sau* und *Schweinerei* enthält *das Schwein*. Beide haben die Bedeutung das Ergebnis von Handlungen eines Schweins bzw. einer Sau zu beschreiben.
Ich denke der Unterschied zwischen beiden ist das **Sauerei mehr Betonung auf das Ergebnis legt**. Wenn man eine außerordentliche Unordnung vorfindet, könnte man fragen:

> Was ist das denn für eine Sauerei?

Die Bedeutung, dass diese Unordnung durch eine Sau hervorgerufen wurde, ist eher zweitrangig.

---

Im Gegensatz dazu ist es bei der **Schweinerei wichtig, wer sie verursacht hat: ein Schwein**.
Die Aussage

> So eine Schweinerei!

bezichtigt den Verursacher ein Schwein zu sein und attestiert ihm moralisches Fehlverhalten. Dabei ist der Grad der Unordnung des Ergebnisses bzw. das Ergebnis selbst eher nebensächlich. Die Handlungen eines korrupten Politikers würde man beispielsweise als Schweinerei bezeichnen. Er hat vielleicht „nur“ ein paar Unterschriften gefälscht (was als solches zwar auch eine Sauerei sein kann), aber die niederen Beweggründe sind in der Situation wichtiger, weshalb es sich eher um eine Schweinerei handelt.

---

Zusammenfassend geht es bei einer Sauerei um das *was* und bei einer Schweinerei um das *wer*. Der Unterschied ist aber sehr subtil.

Außerdem ist festzustellen, dass Schweinerei und Sauerei oft Hand in Hand gehen (Klaue in Klaue?). Einen Verrat im Krieg würde man wohl als Schweinerei bezeichnen. Das Ergebnis eines daraus resultierenden Hinterhaltes als Sauerei.

Comment: "Lust auf ein paar Schweinereien?" -> Ich dachte immer, es ginge hierbei um das "Was". – Oder mit anderen Worten: I'm afraid I don't agree.

Comment: @Em1 Bei "Schweinereien" ist eben nicht genau klar, um *was* es sich eigentlich handelt. Die Bedeutung definiert sich einzig darüber, das es etwas ist, das (i.A.) als moralisch verwerflich angesehen wird/werden könnte. Das ist auch ein Test um zu sehen wie der andere ohne moralische Vorbehalte agiert. Es besteht außerdem die Möglichkeit (und Hoffnung) etwas Unerwartetes zu erleben, da "Schweinereien" unterschiedlich aufgefasst werden. Man spart bewusst die Konkretisierung der Handlung aus und definiert lediglich wessen Denkweise zur Konkretisierung verwendet werden soll: die eines Schweins.

Answer (score 3):

Der Unterschied liegt beim „Namen“. Ich vermute das es sich bei einer *Schweinerei* um etwas allgemein ungepflegtes/rüdes/schroffes handelt, während eine *Sauerei* dann schon spezifischer ist, da eine Sau ja ein Schwein, ein Schwein aber nicht unbedingt eine Sau (weibliches Schwein) sein muss.

Also ist eine *Sauerei* meiner Meinung nach eine Spezifizierung einer Schweinerei, aber muss nicht unbedingt schlimmer, ungepflegter oder ekelhaftiger sein.

*Schweinerei* wird bei Menschen benutzt, um z. B. Aussehen, Verhalten oder  sexuelle Vorgänge zu beschreiben.

Während *Sauerei* häufig genutzt wird, um die Pflege von Gegenständen, Räumen etc. zu beschreiben.

Comment: Also in Bayern ist schon jedes Schwein eine Sau …

Comment: Das ist dann wieder was anderes, aber Definition bleibt Definition ;)

Comment: [Okay, wenn du mir mit Definitionen kommst](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sau) ist eine Sau regional auch der Überbegriff für das Schwein oder die Wutz. Ich hab *Sau* immer als unspezifisches Geschlecht (wie Katze) verstanden.

Comment: ich sagte ja das es was anderes ist...

Comment: @ Jan. Also bei uns ist ein männliches Schwein ein Eber (m. Wildschwein ein Keiler) und ein weibliches eine Sau (w. Wildschwein eine Bache), z.B. eine Sau mit ihren Ferkeln. Gibt es dann bei Euch eine männliche Sau? Meistens ist zwar mit Schwein ein weibliches gemeint, wird ja auch in der Landwirtschaft hauptsächlich gemästet, aber im Grunde ist Schwein erst einmal geschlechtsneutral: Das Schwein, der Eber, die Sau.